Soldier returns home to find family murdered
I watched only the beginning of this movie. First 5 to 10 minutes. Did not seem like an old movie. Probably from the 90s or afterwards. A soldier returns home. His dress and luggage suggest as if he has returned from World War and the scene is taking place in th 1940s. So in front of his house many children are playing. His goes in and finds that no one is there. Although it seems like they knew he was coming and were making preparations. At dining table a fresh cake is there. Then he finds a body. Then he finds another dead body and then finally he goes upstairs where a young woman is lying dead. All killed. Then he spots a child in strange costume. I dont remember what happens exactly but I think he chases that child and falls off on the ground out of his house. Where the playing children surround him.
Can someone identify this movie ?

This is the prologue of Children of the Corn: Genesis (AKA Children of the Corn VIII) from 2011, in which a soldier comes home in 1974 and finds that his family has been killed by kids. Other than the dates, you've described every detail perfectly in that scene, even the cake.
The scene doesn't appear in the trailer, but if you would like to verify this, the movie is currently available in its entirety on Youtube. Here's a frame:

